# In a view of products, add the word "Added" to all products already added to the cart

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have a view that lists all my products, I want to display the word "Added" below every product that has already been added to the shopping cart.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice you aren't asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange sites don't work well with implicit questions. Also, _I want to do this. Any idea is welcome._ is usually too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, I meant to answer this, but for some reason got lost and today this Q just randomly popped into my mind.

If you think creatively, you can accomplish this using CSS [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/x8ntzxax/16/):

1) Create an **attachment** clone of your cart, by clicking the +Add button and selecting attachment. Remove all fields and add a unique field to it, such as SKU. (Make sure you use **For:** this attachment override, so you don't affect your actual cart view).

2) Rewrite your SKU field to be like this

```
<style>
.[field_sku]:before { content: "Added"; position: absolute; } 
</style>
```

3) In in the header section of your products view, add the attachment clone of your cart.

4) In your Products view, wrap each product inside a div class that has the SKU#

```
<div class="[field_sku]">...</div>
```

You could try doing the re-writes through the Views UI, else you can use a template file (hopefully you know how to use template files in Views).